# Search File content using grep for specific numbers of characters at the start of the line

Tags: linux, shell

i have following data in the file

```
Muhammad,Ali    House 12 Mazhar Colony Rawalpindi   0333-5438855
Bushra,Qadir    Gulberg Society Lahore  0234-5321998
Muhammad,Imtiaz Sector E-11/4 Islamabad 0331-4320988
Ehtasham Ul,Haq Chinar House Islamabad  0432-2294712
Summaya,Mumtaz  NUST Hostel-3 Islamabad 0321-7659832
Junaid,Riaz Sadar Road Rawalpindi   0331-5332222
```

i need to search for the lines on which last name is of exactly 5 characters and first name is of 3 or 4 characters long using `grep`. I've tried many many different codes but luck is not favoring me yet. Any ideas on this?

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried?

Comment: just search for the comma, then subtract 1 to see if the last name is the right length.  then do the same for space.

Comment: One good idea is: don't limit yourself to `grep`.

Answer (score 6):

you can try something along the lines of:

```
grep -E '^\w{5},\w{3,4}\s'
```

file content:

```
Muhammad,Ali    House 12 Mazhar Colony Rawalpindi   0333-5438855  
Bushr,Qadi    Gulberg Society Lahore  0234-5321998
Muham,Imt Sector E-11/4 Islamabad 0331-4320988
Ehtasham Ul,Haq Chinar House Islamabad  0432-2294712
Summaya,Mumtaz  NUST Hostel-3 Islamabad 0321-7659832
Junaid,Riaz Sadar Road Rawalpindi   0331-5332222
```

Output:

```
Bushr,Qadi    Gulberg Society Lahore  0234-5321998
Muham,Imt Sector E-11/4 Islamabad 0331-4320988
```

Comment: Thank you Fess for editing my message. I actually didn't want to make all of his homeworks ... :)

Comment: +1, but maybe an explanation is in order, so I added my own.

Answer (score 0):

> I've tried many many different codes but luck is not favoring me yet.

Luck has nothing to do with it. You are searching for five letters, followed by a comma, followed by three or four letters, followed by a space.

```
^    is the beginning of a line
\w   is "a letter"
{n}  means "this many repetitions"
\s   is "a whitespace" (space, tab, nonbreaking space etc.)
```

You just put it all together and obtain the regexp:

```
^\w{5},\w{3,4}\s
```